# Add " and create own json array in php

Tags: php, json

I my php file, I need to make my own Json array.

```
        for($i=1;$i<$arraySize+1;$i++){
            $idJson[$i]=$i.":".$birdIDArray[$i-1];  
        }

        for($i=$arraySize+1 ;$i<$arraySize*2+1; $i++){
            $idJson[$i]=$i.":".$rankArray[$i-($arraySize+1)];
        }
```

When I use

print(json_encode($idJson));

the OUTPUT : ["0:3","1:15","2:3","3:14","4:1","5:2","6:2"]

But i need the output like this ["0":"3","1":"15","2":"3","3":"14","4":"1","5":2","6":"2"]

When I going to add " mark

```
        for($i=1;$i<$arraySize+1;$i++){
            $idJson[$i]=$i.'"'.":".'"'.$birdIDArray[$i-1];  
        }

        for($i=$arraySize+1 ;$i<$arraySize*2+1; $i++){
            $idJson[$i]=$i.'"'.":".'"'.$rankArray[$i-($arraySize+1)];
        }
```

It prints like this
["0:3","1\":\"15","2\":\"3","3\":\"14","4\":\"1","5\":\"2","6\":\"2"]

How can I avoid from printing this \ sign?

Comment: why not simply json_encode($your_array);..? why do you want to create custom...?

Comment: Why don't you just make a normal php array and use `json_encode`?

Comment: `["0":"3", ...` is not a valid JSON array!

Comment: I cannot simply encode my array to json because I need ID and Value pair to get data to my application with Json Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a JSON **object** like this:

```
{"0":"3", ... }
```

The problem here is that Javascript/JSON distinguishes between key-value pairs, which are objects, and numerically indexed lists, which are arrays, while PHP uses arrays for both these things. With `json_encode` it depends on whether the PHP array is a *continuously numerically indexed array*, in which case you get a JSON array, or anything else, in which case you get a JSON object.

What you want is to force a JSON object even for a continuously numerically indexed array. The first question here would be: why?! But if you're really sure you want that (again, **why?!**), there's the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag in PHP 5.3+:

```
echo json_encode(array("3", "15", "3"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// {"0":"3","1":"15","2":"3"}
```

But I'll say again that that's pretty pointless. If you use a regular array like `["3","15","3"]`, the keys to those elements are already implicitly `0`, `1` and `2`. There's no need to enforce them as object keys.

Comment: JSONArray jarray=new JSONArray(result);
    
    for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){    JSONObject json=jarray.getJSONObject(i);
     len=json.getString("0");
     
    }

previously I used json.getString(), but what can I use in here to get data from key0.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to tell me here.

Comment: How can I get values in json array by calling the key(position of the array)?

Comment: In Android's Java? No idea. I can tell you that a JSON array (`[3, 15, 3, ...]`) seems to make the most sense for your data structure. How you work with that in Java I don't know.

Comment: It's worked. It's easy to get values through indexes of JSON array.